# Calling system() from threads with while using ZeroMQ

Tags: c, macos, zeromq

I am having a strange problem with a C ZeroMQ on OS X. I am using the "Multithreaded service in C" code from the guide and I have simply added a call to `system("ls")` after the `sleep(1)` call in the worker_routine function. So that function looks like this:

```
static void *
worker_routine (void *context) {
    //  Socket to talk to dispatcher
    void *receiver = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REP);
    zmq_connect (receiver, "inproc://workers");

    while (1) {
        char *string = s_recv (receiver);
        printf ("Received request: [%s]\n", string);
        free (string);
        //  Do some 'work'
        sleep (1);
        system("ls");
        //  Send reply back to client
        s_send (receiver, "World");
    }
    zmq_close (receiver);
    return NULL;
}
```

When I connect to this server with the sample client in the guide, the `ls` runs but the s_send fails with a NOENT error and no more requests are handled. If I remove the `system("ls")` call everything works fine.

Does anyone know what might be going on?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: How is `s_send()` implemented?

Answer (score 1):

`system` is not thread-safe. See the sample implementation in POSIX for an understanding of why it's not and can't be:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html

In particular, it changes signal dispositions, which are a process-global resource.

It's also possible that the output of `ls` is going somewhere that causes a problem. Where do you intend for the output to go? A good replacement for `system` would be `popen`, which allows you to read back the output of the command and process it or send it wherever you want.